# Groupbyの使用法

Tags: python, pandas

Groupbyを用いて、ある変数が最大の時の別の変数の値を取ってきたいのですが、どのように表記すれば良いでしょうか。
例えば、http://ailaby.com/groupby_easy/
にある「max を適用すると」の箇所で、値引きが最大の時の価格データ（150000,70000）を取ってきたいのですが、どのような関数の表現になるか教えて頂けますでしょうか。

Comment: apply を使う方法もあるかと思います。`df.groupby('CUSTOMER').apply(lambda xdf: df.iloc[xdf.DISCOUNT.argmax()])`

Answer (score 1):

CUSTOMER列をキーにしてfor文で回した例です。
これはあまりスマートではないので、元のDataFrameにインデックスをつけるとよいかもしれません。

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame(
    [['AA', 'TV', 150000, 20000], ['BB', 'Camera', 70000, 10000],
     ['AA', 'Video', 2000, 200], ['AA', 'Video', 3000, 150],
     ['BB', 'TV', 200000, 8000], ['BB', 'Camera', 50000, 5000],
     ['AA', 'Video', 1000, 200]],
    columns=['CUSTOMER', 'PRODUCT', 'PRICE', 'DISCOUNT'])

grouped = df.groupby('CUSTOMER')
discount_max = grouped['DISCOUNT'].max()

for customer in discount_max.index:
    print(df.loc[(df['CUSTOMER'] == customer) & 
                 (df['DISCOUNT'] == discount_max[customer]),
                 'PRICE'].values[0])
```

Comment: metropolisさん、エレガントな回答ありがとうございます。こちらで全く問題なく動きました。
drillerさん、コードありがとうございます。入力データも含めて丁寧に書いて頂き、大変助かりました。